# New question is a duplicate of an old question, someone answers it and closes the old question. Is that the common practice here?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, exact-duplicates

[Why is the cost basis reported by a broker on RSUs 0 USD?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/106319/why-is-the-cost-basis-reported-by-a-broker-on-rsus-0-usd) (posted 4 years ago), was closed by 1 user as a duplicate of [What is the law/regulation which prohibits brokers from reporting basis on RSUs?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/155649/5656) (posted 12 hours ago), where the user had written an answer. Shouldn't we instead close the new question?

Comment: I sometimes forget that my single vote can dup questions with specific tags, and would generally reopen them when I notice that if I think the community might disagree. In this case it seemed trivial to me, so I left it closed and the community/mods can reopen if they disagree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is not a rule saying that the older question has to be the one that remains open.  In general, if we have duplicate questions, we want the best question-and-answer(s) be the one to remain open.  If it is a toss up, we would probably give the edge to the older question.

In this case, it's a tough call.  The older question essentially says, "Is it right that they do this?" and the answers say, "Yes, it is, and here is how you handle it on your Schedule D."  The new question essentially says, "Here is what they do.  What is the law/regulation that requires that they do this?"  The new answer explains the reason behind it and references the tax code.

In my opinion, the new question and answer are more informative, so it makes sense that it would be the one to remain open.